# Expected a value of type 'RootProvider<Object, dynamic>', but got one of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter

Using hooks_riverpod facing the error. The code is as follows

```
class LabelModel extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final popupBackButton = 
               useProvider(popupBackButtonEnabled.state);
    return ......(
       Row(children:[
          popupBackButton ?
              ? IconButton(
                   icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                        onPressed: () {               
                         context.read(popupBackButton)
                                .backEnabled(false);
                   })
              : Container(),

         ......
         .......
         ........
         ..........


         FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                  context.read(popupBackButton)
                         .backEnabled(true);
               },
               child: Text("Add"),
         )
        ],
     )
    );
```

And the place where those are declared globally are

```
class banana extends StateNotifier {
  banana() : super(false);

  void backEnabled(entry) => state = entry;
}

final popupBackButtonEnabled = StateNotifierProvider<banana>(
                               (_) => banana());
```

It Gives me the following error:

======== Exception caught by gesture =======

> The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown while handling a gesture:
> Expected a value of type 'RootProvider<Object, dynamic>', but got one of type 'bool'
> Handler: "onTap"

> Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#27dcd
> debugOwner: GestureDetector

> state: possible
> won arena
> finalPosition: Offset(644.8, 858.0)
> finalLocalPosition: Offset(19.2, 23.0)
> button: 1
> sent tap down

**What Did I do wrong?**

Comment: Can you add `StateNotifier` class to the question?

Comment: @fartem It's inside the second block of code

Comment: `StateNotifier` class is your? Or it imported from a plugin?

Comment: Imported from plugin

Comment: What plugin do you using?

Comment: import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

Comment: `StateNotifier` class contains `state` variable?